# How do I use the union and intersection on a list of Counters of unknown length?

Tags: python, union, counter, operator-keyword

Given that I know how many counters there are, one could easily hard core the `|` operators to get the union of the Counters, e.g.:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter([('a'), ('a', 'bc'), ('a', 'bc'), ('xyz', 'hooli')])
>>> y = Counter([('a'), ('a'), ('a'), ('asd', 'asd')])
>>> z = Counter([('a'), ('a'), ('a'), ('a'), ('a', 'bc')])
>>> x | y | z
Counter({'a': 4, ('a', 'bc'): 2, ('asd', 'asd'): 1, ('xyz', 'hooli'): 1})
```

**But if I have a list of Counters as the input to a function how do I get the union?**

Do I have to loop through each counter and then perform the union? E.g.

```
>>> xyz = [x,y,z]
>>> def counter_union(counters):
...     union = Counter()
...     for c in counters:
...             union = union | c
...     return union
... 
>>> counter_union(xyz)
Counter({'a': 4, ('a', 'bc'): 2, ('asd', 'asd'): 1, ('xyz', 'hooli'): 1})
```

**Is there another way to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `reduce`:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import or_
>>> reduce(or_, [x, y, z])
Counter({'a': 4, ('a', 'bc'): 2, ('xyz', 'hooli'): 1, ('asd', 'asd'): 1})
```

Or if you'd prefer not to import `or_`:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a,b: a|b, [x, y, z])
Counter({'a': 4, ('a', 'bc'): 2, ('xyz', 'hooli'): 1, ('asd', 'asd'): 1})
```

(Similarly for `and_`/`&`.)

Comment: Thanks @DSM, that simplifies the code by quite a lot!!

Comment: As per the dupe `operator.ior`  will avoid creating a new Counter each time `reduce(ior, [x,y,z], Counter())`